# How to reference a class between projects in a Web solution

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a project store a Address class which I want both Web Service project and Web project to use.

Project 1:   (holding Address class)

```
namespace GeoClass
{
    public partial class Address 
    {        
        private string city { get; set; };        
        private string street { get; set; };       
        private string zip { get; set; };
    }
}
```

- Web Service project:  I added the GeoClass as reference

  ```
  using GeoClass;

  namespace WSGeo
  {
       public class jsonGeo : System.Web.Services.WebService
       {
           [WebMethod}
           public jsonOut  GetAddress(Address inputAddr)
           {
              //do something
           }
       }
  }
  ```
- In Web application which is add the WebService project as web service andd add the Project 1 as reference.  I call the method in Webservice likes this:

  ```
  using GeoClass;

  Address inputAddress = GetInputAddress();  //This function pull the data from                  the text boxes 

  string WSResult;
  WSGeo jsonGeo = new WSGeo;

  WsResult = WS.jsonGeo.GetAddress(inputAddress); // I have in invalid argument error right here
  ```

Did I miss something here?  Thanks

Comment: You will need to add the project you are going to reference to references. Have you done that?

Comment: What is the invalid argument error you are receiving?

Comment: @SurgeonofDeath:  I added the reference  Project 1 to both Web Service project and Web App project, and I added the reference webservice from Web service project to the Web App project

Comment: @ragerory: The errors I have are: - cannot convert from 'Project1.Address' to 'Wsgeo.Address'

Comment: Where are you instantiating your `WSGeo` webservice?

Comment: I instantiated in the App project right before I call the web service method.  I forgot to code in, the name jsonGeo is the instantiate

Comment: Can you please provide all the code and not just a snippet so we can properly help? I feel like there is something missing. You need to have something like the following example: `public static WSGeo ws = new WSGeo();` and then call `WSResult = ws.jsonGeo.GetAddress(inputAddress);` - but keep in mind your `using` statement will probably look different and that's what you'll declare in your instance.

Comment: I instantiated like this:  WSGeo jsonGeo = new WSGeo();  and then I call WSResult = jsonGeo.GetAddress(inputAddress);  I don't  need the using statement since the webservice is refered as the Reference service no the Project reference, do I?

Comment: @JennyLe Again, please put all the code in your actual question so we can see it together. Also post the exact error (screenshot, etc).

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer here:  [C# Web Service and Web Site sharing library, service returns different "type" of library object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/791496/c-sharp-web-service-and-web-site-sharing-library-service-returns-different-typ)

I only have this issue with the Web application framework 3.5 (library and web service projects are framework 4.5), when I built another one with framework 4.5 (all web app, web service, and library)  I haven't experienced this problem yet.